# Equation with numbers and subscripts

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

I have no clue how to find the answer in the underlined spot? What does the subscript $9$, $6$ and $3$ mean here?
$$888_9+555_6+222_3= \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ {}_{12}$$

Comment: I think the subscript denotes the basis in which the numbers have to be read. E.g. $888_9=8\cdot 9^2+8\cdot 9 + 8=728.$

Comment: These subscripts probably represent numbers in different bases. If you've never seen this before, [here's](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/bases.html) an introductory webpage on the topic.

Comment: Is this operation can be completed in a scientific calculator?

Comment: Is there some formula which can be used to connect the bases to find the answer?

Comment: There are some few models of calculators that make base conversions, but generally only between decimal, binary, octal, and hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$[n-1][n-1][n-1]_{n} = 1000_n - 1_n \equiv n^3 - 1$$

where the square brackets separate the numerals in a given digits place, and $n^3-1$ is in base $10$.